# Bootstrap nav pills with / sign in the tab link don't works

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, nav-pills

I'm using bootstrap with nav pills. If I put a / sign to the link of the tab, that tab will not work, throws a javascript error in the jquery own code if I click to it. How can I fix this?

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<ul class="nav nav-pills">
  <li class="active"><a data-toggle="pill" href="#ax">First</a></li>
  <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#b/x">Second with / sign</a></li>
  <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#cx">Third</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

The character `/` is a special character, which means you have to escape it.
You do that by adding a `\` in front of it.

---

Your final code would look like:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="pill" href="#ax">First</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#b\/x">Second with / sign</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#cx">Third</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Your solution works, but I need exactly the / sign in the URL without \ . If I load tabs content via Ajax, in my links needs / sign alone. JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dm3p4y1z/1/

Comment: Would this not be as simple as using `.replace("\/", "/")` before submitting the attribute?